# how to fetch data correctly to update UI in useEffect (using useState)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I am using Next.js 13 for the first time and I am trying to fetch a cart object from the api and display it on the UI.

I'm using `useState` to store the cart object and `useEffect` to fetch it. But whenever I do a `setCart()` the UI doesn't get updated, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

This is the code for the `Cart.tsx` component (it's a 'use client' component inside a server component `/carrito/page.tsx`)

```
"use client";

import { Minus, Plus } from "lucide-react";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import swell from "swell-js";
import CartItem from "./CartItem";

const FREE_SHIPPING_THRESHOLD = 500;

const getCartData = async (): Promise<swell.Cart> => {
  const data = await swell.cart.get();
  return data as swell.Cart;
};

const Cart = async () => {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState<swell.Cart>({});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCartData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const data = await swell.cart.get();
      console.log(data) // logs the cart object as I need it
      setCart(data as swell.Cart);
      setIsLoading(false);
      console.log("CART", cart); // logs "{}"
      console.log("ISLOADING", isLoading); // logs "true"
    };

    getCartData();
  }, []);

  function getFreeShippingDifference(subtotal: number) {
    return FREE_SHIPPING_THRESHOLD - subtotal;
  }

  return (
    cart?.id && (
      <section className="container mx-auto">
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-y-2 items-center p-4 py-12">
          <h1>Carrito</h1>
          {getFreeShippingDifference(cart.subTotal as number) < 1 ? (
            <p className="text-gray-400">¡Tienes envio gratis!</p>
          ) : (
            <p className="text-gray-400">
              ¡Te faltan $
              {getFreeShippingDifference(
                cart.subTotal as number
              ).toLocaleString()}{" "}
              para envio gratis!
            </p>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="grid grid-cols-5 text-xs border-b p-4 text-gray-500 uppercase">
          <div className="col-span-3">Productos ({cart.itemQuantity})</div>
          <div className="col-span-1 text-center">Cantidad</div>
          <div className="col-span-1 text-center">Total</div>
        </div>
        {cart?.items?.map((item: any, key: number) => (
          <CartItem item={item} key={key} setCart={setCart} />
        ))}
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-y-2 items-end justify-end p-4">
          <div className="text-sm uppercase text-black">
            Subtotal:{" "}
            <span className="font-semibold">
              ${cart?.subTotal?.toLocaleString()}
            </span>
          </div>
          <p className="text-gray-400">Envio se calcula en el checkout</p>
          <Link
            href="/checkout"
            className="text-sm text-white uppercase bg-sage px-8 py-2 tracking-widest hover:text-white"
          >
            Pagar
          </Link>
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

thanks!

Comment: console.log("CART", cart); // logs "{}"
      console.log("ISLOADING", isLoading); // logs "true"
You are not seeing the updated result in these lines is probably because when you call the state update function, React "schedules" the state update. So it might not be available soon after the set state call.

And in terms of UI not updating, do you have any errors in console?

Not sure if this will make any difference, but still, could you give this a shot
```
return (
{cart?.id && <section... });
```
curly braces, as we are evaluating an expression here.

Comment: @CodeBird thanks for the response! I don't have any errors in the console, also tried wrapping the return in the curly braces and still nothing updates in the UI ☹️

Comment: Can you move the two console logs to just before the return statement? There current location won't help (as mentioned by CodeBird). Your code looks correct so I suspect something is not right with the data and doesn't contain cart.id

Answer (score 0):

***console.log runs before to set the state that's why it returns null***

```
  useEffect(() => {
     const getCartData = async () => {
           ........
      };

    getCartData();
  }, [cart]);
```